# 2 functions in scrapy spider and the second one not running

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy to get the content inside some urls on a page, similar to this question here: 
[Use scrapy to get list of urls, and then scrape content inside those urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913798/use-scrapy-to-get-list-of-urls-and-then-scrape-content-inside-those-urls)

I am able to get the subURLs from my start urls(first def), However, my second def doesn't seem to be passing through. And the result file is empty. I have tested the content inside the function in scrapy shell and it is getting the info I want, but not when I am running the spider.

```html
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
#from scrapy import Spider
from WheelsOnlineScrapper.items import Dealer
from WheelsOnlineScrapper.url_list import urls
import logging
from urlparse import urljoin

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class WheelsonlinespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 logger.info('Spider starting')
 name = 'wheelsonlinespider'
 rotate_user_agent = True # lives in middleware.py and settings.py
 allowed_domains = ["https://wheelsonline.ca"]
 start_urls = urls # this list is created in url_list.py
 logger.info('URLs retrieved') 

 def parse(self, response):

  subURLs = []
  
  partialURLs = response.css('.directory_name::attr(href)').extract()
  
  for i in partialURLs:
   
   subURLs = urljoin('https://wheelsonline.ca/', i)
   yield scrapy.Request(subURLs, callback=self.parse_dealers)
   logger.info('Dealer ' + subURLs + ' fetched')



 def parse_dealers(self, response):


  logger.info('Beginning of page')
  
        dlr = Dealer()
  
     #Extracting the content using css selectors
  try: 
   dlr['DealerName'] = response.css(".dealer_head_main_name::text").extract_first() + ' ' + response.css(".dealer_head_aux_name::text").extract_first()
  except TypeError:
   dlr['DealerName'] = response.css(".dealer_head_main_name::text").extract_first()

  dlr['MailingAddress'] = ','.join(response.css(".dealer_address_right::text").extract()) 
  dlr['PhoneNumber'] = response.css(".dealer_head_phone::text").extract_first()

  logger.info('Dealer fetched ' + dlr['DealerName'])
  
  yield dlr


  logger.info('End of page')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `allowed_domains` list contains the protocol (`https`). It should have only the domain name as per the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains):

```
allowed_domains = ["wheelsonline.ca"]
```

Also, you should've received a message in your log:

> URLWarning: allowed_domains accepts only domains, not URLs. Ignoring URL entry https://wheelsonline.ca in allowed_domains

Comment: Wowwwwwww this did the trick, thank you soooooo much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!